# How to group list of date by a dayofWeek c#

Tags: c#

I would like to group by a List by a DayOfWeek (and time of this DayOfWeek).
For example a week is not from Monday 00:00 until Sunday 24:00, but from Tuesday 12:00 until the next Tuesday 11:59. How could I group by this list?

```
internal class ChartData
{
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, share the example data and expected result

Comment: There's a function called `GroupBy` in the System.Linq namespace. Start there.

Comment: How about [`Enumerable.ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup)?

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Linq GroupBy.

```
var list = new List<ChartData>();
var grouped = list.GroupBy(d => GetWeekNumber(d.Date));
```

You can implement GetWeekNumber(DateTime date) to provde a sequential number depending on which week the ChartData belongs to. The implementation depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

You need to provide more example data.
But maybe it helps